# Solving heat equation with fixed temperature at $x=0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, thermal-conduction

Suppose, there is an insulated 1d rod of length $L$ with initial temperature of $T_{0}$. Suddenly, the beginning of the rod is heated such that its temperature is fixed at $T_{f}$, while the other end is insulated (zero heat flux going in/out).

**Question I'm trying to solve: How long until the other end of the rod reaches $T_{f} - 0.1$ from initial temp of  $T_{0}$, in which $T_{0} < T_{f}$?**

To put it rigorously: solve the heat equation $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \alpha \frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial x^2}$, with the following conditions:
$$
\text{BC:}
$$
$$
T(0, t) = T_{f}
$$
$$
T_{x}(L, t) = 0
$$
$$
IC:
$$
$$
T(x, 0) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
T_{f} & \text{at x = 0} \\ 
T_{0} & \text{at 0 < x ≤ L}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I don't think I can use Fourier series solution, because the initial condition isn't periodic, and if being forced to calculate the Fourier series coefficient, then we are integrating from zero to zero at x=0, which is just zero and doesn't make sense.

I also tried using Fourier integral method, since although non-periodic initial condition, we are still integrating from zero to zero at x=0.

So, the problem is the initial condition is like a unit impulse, where only the beginning of the rod's face is heated and fixed at certain temperature.

**EDIT 1:**
What I mean by integrating zero to zero, is for example in the fourier integral, it yields to:
$$
T(x,t) = \frac{T_{f}}{\sqrt{\alpha\pi t}}\int_{0}^{0}e^{-\frac{(x-z)^{2}}{4\alpha t}}dz + \frac{T_{0}}{\sqrt{\alpha\pi t}}\int_{0+}^{L}e^{-\frac{(x-z)^{2}}{4\alpha t}}dz
$$, which the first integral evaluate to zero?

**EDIT 2:**

As JohnMcSwag mentioned below, the end of the rod will need infinite time to reach $T_{f}$, as the end of the rod will only asymptotically approach $T_{f}$. However, I'm looking for a finite time solution. Hence, let's define such that the rod end temperature is arbitrarily close to $T_{f}$, say within 0.1 temp unit.

**EDIT 3:**
I have just read [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and can see why this question might be view as a homework question. However, I would like to specifically mention that this problem is not school work or anything. It is inspire from a personal project of mine and I am curious on how to solve the problem.
Nevertheless, I would like to address point 2 of this [post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). The specific concept I'm having problem is the integrating zero to zero to determine the fourier coefficient in the fourier series case and similarly integrating zero-to-zero for the fourier integral case. I will leave the above question un-edited so that people can see the problem I'm trying to solve and determine whether solving the heat equation is the right approach or not.

Comment: If someone, have a solution to the above question without necessarily solving the heat equation, then please do enlighten me. Note that we assume the rod is uniform with constant thermal conductivity, specific heat capacity, and density.

Comment: This is silly: you really only need to solve the HE, with boundary and initial stated, and be done with it.

Comment: @Gert, If you can solve the HE with the given boundary and initial condition, then please do post it, because, I don't think solving the HE with the given BC and IC is as straight forward, since the IC is like a unit pulse

Comment: That's not a 'unit pulse'. You're over-thinking. Solution has been posted g-d knows how many times.

Comment: I would like to mention that this is not homework question. This problem was inspired from a personal project of mine and I am curious on how to solve the problem. @Gert, please kindly show links, if you really think that this has been posted "g-d knows how many times", I think that the problem's boundary conditions is quiet unique and have not found anything like it after hours of looking things up on the internet

Comment: See also Crank's *Mathematics of Diffusion* and online resources from a search for `"heat equation" finite line` ([example](http://www.math.umbc.edu/~jbell/pde_notes/08_Heat%20Equation_General%20Solution.pdf)).

Comment: I disagree with those who voted to close this. This is a pretty difficult question about how to incorporate an unusual boundary condition in the heat equation - a conceptual question, not asking someone to complete a calculation. And frankly I don't know the answer currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll set $L=1$, $\alpha=1$, $T_f=0$ and $T_0=1$ (rescale time, affine change for temperature). This way, the time independent boundary conditions are homogeneous. Your problem is now:
$$
\begin{align}
T(t=0)&=1\\
T(x=0)&= 0 \\
\partial_xT(x=1) &= 0 \\
\partial_tT&= \partial_x^2T
\end{align}
$$

**Method 1**

One way is to expand the temperature into modes. To accommodate the boundary conditions, you'll need to slightly modify the usual Fourier modes, but the method is pretty standard. In your case, the relevant modes are indexed by $n\in\mathbb N$:
$$
\begin{align}
-e_n'' &= k_n^2 e_n\\
e_n(0)&= 0 \\
e_n'(1) &= 0\\
e_n(x) &= \sin(k_nx) \\
k_n &= \pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$
They form an orthonormal basis:
$$
\begin{align}
\langle e_m,e_n\rangle &= \int_0^1 e_m(x)e_n(x)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1(\cos[\pi(n-m)x]-\cos[\pi(n+m+1)x])dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\delta_{mn}\\
\end{align}
$$
Expanding your initial conditions in these modes:
$$
\begin{align}
T(t=0) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty e_nT_n \\
T_n &= 2\int_0^1 e_n(x)T(t=0,x)dx \\
&= 2\int_0^1 \sin\left[\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)x\right]dx \\
&= \frac{4}{\pi(2n+1)} \\
T(t=0) &= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}e_n
\end{align}
$$

You can now evolve it in time:
$$
\begin{align}
T &= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2n+1}e^{-k_n^2t}e_n
\end{align}
$$

As usual, for large time, only the fundamental mode is relevant and you can easily arrive at your answer by hand.

**Method 2**

Similar to Fourier's original method you can try to extend the original problem to the entire line. There is already a hint of that looking at the previous mode expansion, because the formula makes sense on the entire line and gives a 4-periodic solution. Only unlike in Fourier's case where he simply periodised the solutions since he didn't have boundary conditions, you need to take into account the boundary solutions.

The usual trick is that when a function is symmetric (resp. antisymmetric) at a point, the derivative (resp. function) vanishes there. You therefore extend the initial condition by antisymmetry/symmetry. Explicitly, starting with $T(t=0)=T_0$ defined on $(0,1)$, you extend $T$ to a new function $\tilde T$ defined on the entire line $\mathbb R$:
$$
\tilde T(x) = \begin{cases}
T(x-\lfloor x\rfloor) & \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 0 \, [4] \\
T(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)) & \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 1 \, [4] \\
-T(x-\lfloor x\rfloor) & \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 2 \, [4] \\
-T(1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)) & \lfloor x\rfloor \equiv 2 \, [4]
\end{cases}
$$

Note that now the initial condition is 4-periodic and the symmetry/antisymmetry conditions are conserved by the heat equation. You are therefore back to a case of Fourier series. You just need to expand the square wave corresponding to your initial condition into Fourier series. You'll get rigorously the same series as in method 1.

**Method 3**

Another classic method is the method of images. It has the benefit of more easily revealing the behaviour at initial times, whereas the previous two methods are more relevant for longer times.

The idea is to stay in real space and convolve with the initial condition Green's function:
$$
\begin{align}
G(t=0)&=\delta(x)\\
\partial_t G &= \partial_x^2 G\\
G &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}e^{-x^2/4t}
\end{align}
$$

So that the Cauchy problem is solved by a spatial convolution:
$$
T = G\star T_0
$$

In your case, you need to calculate the convolution of the Gaussian kernel with the square wave. One way is to realise that the derivative is an alternating Dirac comb, so integrating by parts, you get:
$$
\begin{align}
T &= -1+\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \text{erf}\left(\frac{x-4n}{\sqrt{4t}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x-4n-2}{\sqrt{4t}}\right) \\
\text{erf}(x) &= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-\xi^2}d\xi
\end{align}
$$

You can check that both formulas agree directly by using the Poisson summation formula.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AXensen, mention a good point. More specifically, the tiny extent of the heated region, is practically zero, because is only heated at the face of the rod.

Comment: As Gert said, there is no unit pulse. Mathematically, the specific value of functions on a 0 measure set is irrelevant, you need to think in terms of $L^2$ (or better still distributions). Did you plot the given solution with say 10 terms? You'll see that it does follow your requirements.

Comment: I'll add alternative methods perhaps the mode expansion one was too advanced for you

Comment: @AXensen I forgot the newline. The initial condition is what the OP asked, uniform over he interval. As I said in a previous comment, the precise value at $0$ is irrelevant, you need to think in terms of $L^2$ or distribution: the correct mathematical setting. Note that for all $t>0$, $T(x\to0^+)=0$.  If you want it to be $0$ over a finite region about the origin, then this would change the problem, which is not what the OP's looking for.

Comment: OMG, @LPZ's answer is too complicated for my mediocre math knowledge, but I believe is correct and need time to properly digest it. However, I would like to ask two questions: 1. In method 2, can you clarify what is $\tilde{T}$ 2. In method 3, can you recommend links or sources for understanding how you get from $T = G*T_{o}$ to the final $T = -1+...$

Comment: @LPZ I get it now. 1 in your solution is the "initial temperature" and f(0)=0 for all t, which could be the perturbed temperature. And yeah with your edit $k_n$ makes sense. Nice work. I'll delete all my comments and you can delete your responses if you want.

Comment: Also, in method 3, what is n?

Comment: in method 3, $n$ is the index for the sum. If I have some time, i’ll detail a bit more the method 3. Glad it helps. Even if you don’t fully understand the methods, you can always check numerically the formulas.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the temperature $T_f$ would never be reached. Instead, I think $T_f$ is the value of the limit if $t\rightarrow\infty$ for all $x$. This is because you heat the rod with $T_f$, so any place $x$ will have a difference that asymptotically goes to zero as its temperature goes to $T_f$, because the increase in temperature at a certain place is dependent on the difference with it's neighbors according to the heat equation. Therefore, the actual temperature $T_f$ would never be reached.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I'm editing my question. Because this is not the solution im looking for. I want a finite time solution such that the end of the rod gets really close to $T_{f}$. However, I realised that this is not very rigorous. so let's define really close to be within 0.1 temp unit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In that case I would follow the advice of @naturallyInconsistent, since that seems to be the general way to solve problems with rods connected to a source only from t=0 onwards. This [link](http://www.math.utah.edu/~smale/Math%203150-002%20Fall%202014/LectureNotesA.pdf) may help.

Comment: I don't think the link you provide is the same. In that link, the boundary condition is just fixed temperature one the 2 ends

Comment: Yeah, but the same technique still applies. You just have to use different boundary conditions, which I believe means you'll get (n+1/2) instead of n. In the question you mention that you have difficulty with solving the heat equation for this case, which makes sense because I'm not sure the Fourier coefficients are allowed for this type of initial field. If you instead work backwards from the final solution, define the deviation as the thing you want to solve (you can check that this gives the same heat equation) and then use Fourier's method, you can solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1. What would be steady state final solution after infinite time has passed?
2. Recast your problem so that you are computing the deviation from this final solution.
3. The deviation has trivial boundary conditions, and thus you just have to solve the initial conditions. The problem is ready to be done via Fourier's method. Express the initial conditions as initial conditions of the Fourier coefficients.
4. Profit.
5. Numerically sum the series and plot to see that your results are not crazy.